# Does Camera Power Consumption Lower Without Output?

Tags: power, current, camera, power-consumption

I have a camera with power consumption listed at 24 VDC +10% @ 1.5 A max.
That same camera has a built-in output for an external light, 24VDC @ 750 mA max.

Without the external light output, will my max power consumption be 750 mA max?

I keep hearing that current draw of the camera will remain @ 1.5 A max, however, I do not see why.

Model of the camera is a Cognex 7600. Below is a snip from the datasheet.

[image: is7600_DataSheetSnip]

Answer (score 0):

It's imposible to be sure without handling the actual hardware,
and difficult to guess without seeing the data-sheet of the camera.

I would expect the presence of the light to increase the power draw of the system.

It could be that running the light increases the draw to 1.5A + 0.75A = 2.25A or it could be that the camera itself draws 0.75A and the light when present brings the total upto 1.5A